# Google Container Engine Private Kubernetes LoadBalancer

Tags: networking, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've just started working with Kubernetes at work and was wondering if there is an easy way to expose a service to a private, within google cloud, network. Everything works fine when exposed using the standard service type of `LoadBalancer`. It just seems strange to expose everything over a publicly addressable network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The services can be exposed to any other pod in your cluster by simply using *no type at all*, or setting `ClusterIP` to 'None' for a [Headless Service](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/user-guide/services.html#headless-services) which gives you access to the IPs of all the selected Pods.

To expose to the outside world securely, there are a couple options, but nothing super easy:

- setup TLS authentication for your services, so they are exposed to the outside but require authentication.
- use VPN into your cluster: this is the solution i adopted, using this project: https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn 
  I have a pending PR that produces the Kubernetes Secrets file, so as to not have to keep credentials inside the image.

**EDIT (2017-08):**

There is also now 2 kube-openvpn projects based on the above:

- https://github.com/redspread/kube-openvpn
- https://github.com/pieterlange/kube-openvpn